# Difference between np.transpose(y) and np.transpose([y])

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, data-analysis, numpy-ndarray

Suppose I have `y = [1,2,3]` (1 X 3 matrix) then `np.transpose(y)` should be a (3 X 1) matrix but the function transpose is returning the same (1 X 3) matrix.
If I run `np.transpose([y])` then it's returning expected (3 X 1) matrix.
Can anyone explain what's happening here?

Comment: The matrix is a 2 dimensional array. One dimensional array is not a matrix.

Comment: How do you get 1x3?  I only see 1 set of []?  `transpose` first does `np.array([1,2,3])`.  Check that array's shape.

Answer (score 0):

`transpose` reverses the axes order. if `y = [1,2,3]` there is only one axis: `y.shape = (3,)`. So `transpose` won't do anything.

If `y=[[1,2,3]]` the there are 2 axes: `y.shape = (1,3)` and `transpose` will work as you expect.